# SpannableStringBuilder append() NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, exception, spannablestringbuilder

```
// Documentation from interface
public SpannableStringBuilder append(CharSequence text) {
    int length = length();
    return replace(length, length, text, 0, text.length());
}
```

`SpannableStringBuilder` source code `append()` function doesn't avoid `NullPointerException`??
If text is null, `append()` function definitely throw `NullPointerException`. 
It's easily be forgotten to check every case if text is null. For example the text may from the server. 
Anyone has a better idea for `SpannableStringBuilder` `append()` function to avoid npe?

Comment: I'd say that the creators of this class left it up to the caller to make sure that a non `null` text is passed to the method.  And, I don't see anything wrong with that decision.

Comment: `SpannableStringBuilder#append(CharSequence text)` is not final - you can override it in some your custom class

Comment: It is up to you not to forget it. Or just extend this class, and override `append`, and use your extended class.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `SpannableStringBuilder` in your own class and put the `null` check there  .